# How do you disable semicolons in ESLint for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to not allow semicolons to be placed at the end of lines in my Javascript code using ESLint. `"semi"` and `"no-extra-semi"` don't work, and I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You want to set `semi` to `["error", "never"]`. This will error when there is a semicolon. Documentation can be found here https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi#never

Comment: Thanks! This works, but is there an integer corresponding to "never"? 2 corresponds to "error".

Comment: @KenMueller I believe there are 3 integer values (0, 1, 2) that can be used to set eslint rules, respectively, to "off", "warn" or "error" (https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules).